Excel formula won't work in every cell
Hope you're all well!
I'm currently calibrating distance to see how far different types of Boccia balls travels on a different number/level on a customised ramp
The ball's distance differs due to a change in temperature, humidity level and type of court. Thus I'm calibrating the balls before any drills and games.
I calibrated the balls fully in .25cm increments on 1 sheet and in another sheet I only calibrate every metre and let the excel formula to calculate the increments based on the previous completed sheet.
My formula: =IFERROR(('Full Data Red'!H42/'Full Data Red'!H38)*B38,0) works in some cells but not others.
e.g. currently works for all increments between 5-6m, 7-8, 9-10m. If I put the same code for any of the increments between 4-5m, 6-7m or 8-9m then all increments throughout the sheet don't work/updateScreenshot of sheet and formula when adjusting the metre value

Updated info
Calibration sheet simplified example
More info
The cells that are split in prematch calibration (3,4,5,8.5,8.75,9,9.25 & 9.5 metres) are where I'll be entering my own raw number.
Currently the code predicts (6,7,8,8.25,9.75 & 10 metres) based on initial calibration
I'm trying to get it to predict all the other in between increments but the code won't work and temporary I'm using the code below to get an estimate but it's no where near as accurate
=IFERROR((B55+B53)/2,0) for .25 increments
=IFERROR((B57+B53)/2,0) for .5 increments
=IFERROR((B58+B54)/2,0) for .75 increments
Really appreciate your help!
All the best,
Moustie

What cells does it work in and what cells does it not? How do you know it's not working? It might also be useful to have a minimal reproducing example with data from both sheets included. SHowing the columns headers and row numbers in your screencap is also a good idea

it may be that you have merged cells which is throwing off the formuas in the non-working cells...

^^^ well spotted!

Hi, hope all is well! I put more detail in the question above with a link to a simplified example.

Try building the sheet with no merged cells. Merged cells are almost always a bad idea and they don't seem to accomplish anything here
